# (pytest) Why doesn't property mock work in fixture?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a class with some properties. In my test, I need to set up a fixture, and have the properties mocked. However, the patch only works in the fixture function, not when the fixture is called. Any idea how to fix this?

Here is the simplified version of the problem. Let's assume that this is my class `Panda`:

```py
class Panda(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.panda_name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.panda_name
```

and this is my test

```py
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch, PropertyMock
from tmp import Panda


@pytest.fixture
@patch(
    'tmp.Panda.name',
    new_callable=PropertyMock,
    return_value="yuanyuan")
def fixture_panda(mk_name):
    p = Panda("this name should not matter")
    print(p.name)  # print "yuanyuan"
    return p


def test_panda_fixture(fixture_panda):
    p = fixture_panda
    print(p.name)  # print "this name should not matter"
    # this test fails
    assert p.name == "yuanyuan"
```

The first print function in `fixture_panda` would print `yuanyuan`, which means the propertyMock works as expected. However the 2nd print function in `test_panda_fixture` print `this name should not matter`, which means the propertyMock doesn't work here. Any idea why this happens and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to monkeypatch something in `pytest`, you can use their built-in fixture `monkeypatch`, which can be inserted into all fixtures with `scope = function`. Here is an example from my codebase:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def no_jwt(monkeypatch):
  """Monkeypatch the JWT verification functions for tests"""
  monkeypatch.setattr("flask_jwt_extended.verify_jwt_in_request", lambda: print("Verify"))
```

If I apply it to your example, I think something like this should work:

```
@pytest.fixture
def fixture_panda(monkeypatch, mk_name):
  monkeypatch.setattr('tmp.Panda.name', "yuanyuan")
  p = Panda("this name should not matter")
  print(p.name)  # print "yuanyuan"
  return p
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three problems.  Firstly, you're patching the fixture function but you should be patching the test function.  This is because the way you've written it, the assertion falls outside the scope of the patching.

Secondly you should ditch the superfluous `mkname`.

Thirdly, your `return_value` is in the wrong place; it needs to apply to the `PropertyMock` object which the patch returns, not as a parameter to the patching function.  When using `new_callable` you need to set it within the test setup, e.g.:

```
@patch('tmp.Panda.name', new_callable=PropertyMock)
def test_panda_fixture(mock_name, fixture_panda):
    mock_name.return_value = "yuanyuan"
    ...
```

However you can do it within the decorator by using `new` instead of `new_callable`.  Here's a working version which shows that approach:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch, PropertyMock
from tmp import Panda


@pytest.fixture
def fixture_panda():
    p = Panda("this name should not matter")
    print(p.name)  # print "yuanyuan"
    return p


@patch('tmp.Panda.name', new=PropertyMock(return_value="yuanyuan"))
def test_panda_fixture(fixture_panda):
    p = fixture_panda
    print(p.name)  # print "this name should not matter"
    # this test fails
    assert p.name == "yuanyuan"
```